# Cannot drag folder to Ubuntu in VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vmware-fusion

My host is Mac OS X and I used VMware Fusion 3 to install Windows 7, Windows XP, and Ubuntu Linux. I can drag and drop folders between Windows 7/XP and Mac OS X, but I cannot do the same for Ubuntu. I try to look for setting but nothing relevant. Is it a problem with Mac, VMware, or Ubuntu? How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a post on the VMware blog on [copy & pasting between host of vm](http://blogs.vmware.com/vanswers/2010/05/drag-drop-copy-pastebest-of-the-docs.html)

*A couple of overall tips to begin with. If you're having trouble with drag-and-drop/copy-and-paste: make sure that you have updated your Workstation, Player, or VMware Fusion to the latest version, and **that you have the current version of VMware Tools installed***

Do you have VMware tools installed on the Ubuntu virtual machine?